# Decimal separator comma not working in currency field in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, currency

I have a currency field (16,2) in Salesforce, with € as currency and comma as the decimal separator. When I try to import Salesforce reports and their data to Marketing Cloud in interactions --> import, the data in the currency field is distorted, because the decimal separator in Marketing Cloud in the currency field is a dot. This means that values are completely wrong, e.g. 12,00 € in Salesforce would be 1200.00 € in Marketing Cloud. How can I fix this? I have not found a way to change the decimal separator in Marketing Cloud to comma, and I don't want to change it to a dot in Salesforce, because we operate in a country where the separator is always a comma, so this would mix all of our reports.

EDIT: I also noticed that when Marketing Cloud creates an automatic data extension for journeys using Salesforce data as entry source, with the currency field in the entry data, this works just fine and the separator is changed from comma to dot without the actual value being changed. But when trying to create the data extension with interactions --> import, the values get distorted.

Comment: I don't see a way to change the separator from a dot to a comma. In case you don't need this field in filters (Data filters, decision splits,..), why not store the data as a string and convert it when needed to a decimal with AMPScript/SSJS/SQL? Ex: here is the function to convert a string to a decimal in AMPScript: 
https://ampscript.guide/formatnumber/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to change the separator from a dot to a comma.

In case you don't need this field in filters (Data filters, decision splits,..), why not store the data as a string and convert it when needed to a decimal with AMPScript/SSJS/SQL?

Ex: here is the function to convert a string to a decimal in AMPScript: ampscript.guide/formatnumber

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately I do need the field for dynamic content rules, and decision splits. I noticed that when Marketing Cloud creates an automatic data extension for journeys using Salesforce data as entry source, with the currency field in the entry data, this works just fine and the separator is changed from comma to dot without the actual value being changed. But when trying to create the data extension with interactions --> import, the values are distorted.